# Plotting data from set of files in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a large number of files containing xy-data that I would like to plot in one plot. I know I can do that manually and bit by bit which is ok for only several files, but not for larger numbers.

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{data01.dat}
0   0
1   1
2   2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data02.dat}
0   1
1   2
2   0
\end{filecontents}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {data01.dat};
    \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {data02.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to plot a set of numbered files or even all files in a certain folder autimatically in pgfplots?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `\foreach` loop (part of `pgf`):

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{data01.dat}
0   0
1   1
2   2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data02.dat}
0   1
1   2
2   0
\end{filecontents}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \foreach \num in {01,02} {
        \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {data\num.dat};
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For large numbers of files, you can define in terms of a series, like:

```
\foreach \num in {1,2,...,18} {
  \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1] {data\ifnum\num<10 0\fi\num.dat};
};
```

to plot `data01.dat`, `data02.dat`, `data03.dat`, ..., `data18.dat`. Thanks to egreg in the comments for the quick leading zero solution.

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction. It works nicely when deleting the leading zeros from the file names. A solution including (multiple) leading zeros or all files from one folder would still be appreciated, though.

Comment: `\makeatletter\let\twodigits\two@digits\makeatother` in the preamble and `data\twodigits{\num}.dat` in the `\foreach` code should do.

Comment: Or, directly, `data\ifnum\num<10 0\fi\num.dat`